# Передать аргумент из класса в форму

Tags: c#, winforms, методы

Использую метод `invoke action` в форме работает отменно)

```
public void Active(Panel l)
{
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Invoke((Action)(() => { l.Visible = false; }));
      });
}
```

Но как работать через класс не знаю.

Мне нужно через класс вызвать его в главной форме ( использую кнопки )

P.S: При нажатие на кнопку, через класс ( где вызывается метод, что-то делается) оповестить пользователя, что  метод сработал нормально. Я же передаю информацию в `label` на форме.

**[Обновление]**

На каждой кнопки вызываю данный метод:

```
Active(panel1);
```

чтобы панель через 2сек скрывалась.

Я же хочу метод Active перенести в класс, и от туда уже присваивать каждой кнопки метод

Comment: Как насчет ивентов?

Comment: @AGS17, мало знаю к сожалению, с делегатами почти не работал.

Comment: Можно и без делегатов обойтись. Используйте `EventHandler`

Comment: @AGS17 а EventHandler уже не делегат? Такой же делегат, но с предопределенной сигнатурой и все.

Comment: Посмотрите ответ на ваш вопрос про мониторинг сети, и замените в нем EventHandler на EventHandler<T>. Определяете собственный класс-наследник от EventArgs с нужными полями и работаете с событием, так же как работаете с ними в формах.

Comment: @rdorn подразумевалось, что можно обойтись без делегатов с точки зрения пользователя.

Comment: Можете дать пример с использованием `EventHandler` на данном примере? я не могу сообразить, как это реализовывается..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что Вы хотите можно сделать так:

**Класс у которого мы вызываем метод**

```
class ActiveClass
{
    public void Active(Control control)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            control.Invoke((Action)(() => control.Hide()));
        });
    }
}
```

**Код формы**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveClass active = new ActiveClass();
        active.Active(button1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я хочу при нажатие на кнопку вызывался метод ( который написан в другом классе) метод который будет скрывать окно панели на форме через промежуток времени.`Invoke((Action)(() => { l.Visible = false; }));` собственно чтобы другим панелям можно было присвоить значение `void Active(Panel l) {...{ l.Visible = false; } }`

Comment: Обновил) может теперь ясно будет чего я добиваюсь)

Comment: @ArteS, я переделал ответ

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение данной проблемы) Как и хотелось через класс!

```
public static void Active(Panel l)
{
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        l.Invoke((Action)(() => { l.Visible = false; }));
      });
}
```